# Share data:image on facebook API share_open_graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have the following code -

```
      const canvas = jQuery(`#canvasId`);

      const facebookShare = jQuery(`#share`);

      facebookShare.on("click", () => {
        FB.ui({
          method: 'share_open_graph',
          action_type: 'og.shares',
          action_properties: JSON.stringify({
              object: {
                  'og:url': "sitename.com",
                  'og:title': title,
                  'og:image': canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
              }
          })
        }, function(response){});
      });
```

Which should share the image of the canvas on the fb share button click, but the facebook is returning me an error message

> Object Invalid Value: Object at URL
>   'http://sitename.com/#share'
>   of type 'object' is invalid because the given value
>   'data:image/png;base64,...................' for property
>   'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Any ideas how to fix that? I would need to retrieve a shareable image from the canvas and use it in the share window.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should change the "sitename.com" to whatever it is supposed to be... "sitename.com" seems to be a placeholder... I suggest you look at the instructions from wherever you got the code.

Comment: I just changed the sitename.com from my site name to sitename.com , so I don't advertise the site. It's not shouting about the sitename, it's shouting about og:image:url :( .

Comment: You can not use a data URI in that place. It needs to be an HTTP(S) URL. Or you can also upload it to Facebook first, so that you can then refer to it in further OG stories your app publishes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api